# ¿Por qué da error de paréntesis inesperado?

Tags: r

El código que tengo es este de aquí.

```
bullying_recoded<- as.data.frame (sapply(1:8),function(i))
```

Y sale el error "unexpected token ')', aun cuando es la forma correcta de cerrar el paréntesis. ¿Alguien sabe a qué puede deberse?

Mi gratitud por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esa línea hay dos errores de sintaxis, uno tiene que ver con el `sapply` y el otro con `function`. Con respecto al `sapply(1:8)` los paréntesis cierran antes de especificar el argumento `FUN`, el cual no tiene un argumento por defecto.
El otro problema de sitaxis está luego de la coma en `function(i)`, si te fijas en `?function` espera, luego de la lista de los argumentos, la expresión, que en este caso no la estarías completando.

La solución:
Mover el paréntesis del `sapply` al final de la línea y especificar nuestra expresión de la función (en este caso expresión sin comandos) adicionando `{}` luego de `function(i)`.

`bullying_recoded<- as.data.frame (sapply(1:8,function(i){}))`